# keyup on up arrow of time input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the value of #End to be always equal to value of #Start, even if someone is only doing keyup on the #Start without releasing the mouse

```js
// method 1 : this works only with on change not with keyup
$('#start').change(function() {
    $('#end').val($('#start').val())
})

// method 2 : this does not work with keyup at all, donno why
$(document).on('keyup', '#start', function() {
    $('#end').val($('#start').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="time" id="start" value="00:00">
<input type="time" id="end" value="00:00">
```

[image]

How is it possible ?

Comment: Use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead...

Comment: What if someone changes value of `#end` ? If that is the case then, `$(document).on('input', '#start,#end', function() {
  $('#start,#end').val($(this).val())
});`

Comment: input event worked , this is the first time i heard of such an event, for the #end my question is to simplify my problem

Comment: @Yoshi i dont know why keypup did not work

Comment: The `keyup` event is raised when you release a key on your keyboard. It has nothing to do with your mouse.

Comment: oh sorry i messed up

Comment: I think I understand now, you want it to work while holding a key *down*? If so, it's quite obvious why `keyup` is not the right event to listen to then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `input` event or bind all event you want it to listen to (equivalent to the input-event but I thinks its more cross-browser reliable):

```js
//input event
$(document).on('input', '#start', function() {
    $('#end').val($('#start').val())
});

//all events
$(document).on('change keyup keydown keypress click blur', '#start1', function() {
    $('#end1').val($('#start1').val())
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="time" id="start" value="00:00">
    <input type="time" id="end" value="00:00">
    <br><br>
    <input type="time" id="start1" value="00:00">
    <input type="time" id="end1" value="00:00">
```

I'd prefer the `input` event because it updates on every change but as I said, cross-browser...

Comment: @MehdiSouregi yeah, i remember when i heared about it for the first time. Be careful though because of cross-browser-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try using Click and Keyup, it will work

```js
// method : this will works with Click and Keyup events
$('#start').on('click keyup',function() {
    $('#end').val($('#start').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="time" id="start" value="00:00">
<input type="time" id="end" value="00:00">
```

Comment: There is a problem with your code in far-sight.
when somone inserts a value via arrow-keys it wont work anymore.

Comment: @zeropublix - thanks for the vision. You were right. I have updated answer.